# How to create a hash that is similar for similar input?

Tags: string, algorithm, file, hash, comparison

I want to create a database with files. And, to easily search these files, I want to use some kind of hashing technique. However, I don't only want to find files that are EXACTLY the same, but also check if parts of the files are the same(i.e., the files are similar). in other words, similar files should have similar hashes.

This means that this kind of hash is not really a cryptographic hash because there should not be an 'avalanche effect' (avalanche effect means that each bit of data affects ALL other bits of other data.)

Another thing is that the hash does not need to be one-way, since it isn't used for securitypurposes but for the comparing of files.

So in essence, I'm searching for an algorithm that can create an unique hash for each unique input that:

- Has (almost) no collision
- Creates a similar output for similar inputs
- Is shorter than the original file (otherwise it would be faster to simply compare the original files instead).

I was thinking of something like adding the first two characters together, then adding the 3rd and 4rth together, etc. However, this has a HUGE amount of collision since "1+4" is the same as "2+2", etc

I really have no idea how to start. Could somebody enlighten me please? :)

Comment: This is probably very difficult. Look into http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agrep

Comment: if the job is to find files with common bytes, [ssdeep](http://ssdeep.sourceforge.net/), is great at that.

Comment: You'd be looking at creating a compression algorithm, followed by a sort. You'd be using the same frequency tables for all of the compressed inputs so as to make things deterministic.

Comment: @DanD.: that looks like a _great_ link in this context

Comment: I know this might get down voted as it doesn't answer really your question, but have you considered using a purpose built search framework like Lucene (http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/index.html) instead? There are java and .Net versions. It really is a joy to use and is extremely fast and efficient and flexible. Just a thought...

Comment: It would help to know what kind of data you have -- the ideal algorithm will vary depending on the nature of the data.  But for some general ideas look up "Soundex".  Not that you would use Soundex per se, but it's the general approach you'd need to take.

Comment: It sounds like what you really need is a way to do 'near match' indexing of files - hashing is just one way you might accomplish that. Why not ask the more general question, and describe the context (Eg, what the files are) while you're at it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is commonly called the [near duplicate detection](http://glinden.blogspot.com/2008/08/clever-method-of-near-duplicate.html) problem and is not easy to solve; I would recommend the [simhash](http://166.111.80.199/wiki/images/4/41/2007-Sim_Hash.pdf) algorithm (code is [here](http://code.google.com/p/simhash/)).

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently using ssdeep to achieve the same effect and I'm getting pretty good results with it.

I've also read that sdhash is better than ssdeep.